# how to load a local stylesheet for a remote website

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'd like to load an additional local stylesheet for a remote website to override the remote website's styles.

I've gone to Chrome inspector > Sources > Overrides > + Select folder for overrides > Selected folder where my custom local stylesheet lives;

When I reload the page, the local stylesheet is not applied.

[image]

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add local stylesheet to remote website through **Chrome overrides**.

This is how it works.

> 1. You specify a directory where DevTools should save changes.
> 2. When you make changes in DevTools, DevTools saves a copy of the modified file to your directory.
> 3. When you reload the page, DevTools serves the local, modified file, rather than the network resource.